# How to rearrange skills in Puzzle Quest 2?

Tags: puzzle-quest-2

At some point in conquest it said that I would be able to rearrange my skills (strength, intelligence, etc) if I go somewhere, but where is that place located exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Puzzle Quest 2 do you have? You can respec on the XBLA version but not on the DS version. You go to Jarrum Blackstone in the Chapel. I *believe* you can do this anytime after level 21, but I haven't gotten that far myself yet.